# Wordpress: show current logged user comments and author post and conments

Tags: wordpress

I am looking for a solution for WordPress to hide post comments of other commenters but the logged in user and the post author.

In other words, let's say I am the logged-in user and I post a comment on an article or post. Also other users have written or are writing comments on the same post. I am interested, as the logged-in user, to see only my own comments and replies between myself and the author. The rest of the comments between the author and other users to be hidden from my view.

Schematic, it would look like a conversation between the Author and the Logged-in user. The Author can have multiple conversations with other users on the same comments section, however the Logged-in user to see only his own conversation with the Author.

**Article or Post Title**

*Author name*

## Article body ....

*Comments section:*

- Logged-in User Comment1 (visible)

  - Author Reply1 (visible)
  - Logged-in User Reply1 (visible)
  - Author Reply2 (visible)
  - Logged-in User Reply2 (visible)
    ...
- Other User Comment1 (hidden)

  - Author Reply1 (hidden)

I have tried searching for plugins, but nothing can do that yet

Also I have tried [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22585442/wordpress-how-to-hide-comments-to-non-logged-users), however it did not work.

Answer (score 0):

You can use, for example, [`get_comments()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_comments/) to get comments, and specify the ID of the users, the comments you want to get. Example:

```php
$author_id = $post->post_author;
$user_id = get_current_user_id(); 

$comments = get_comments( [
  'author__in' => [ $author_id, $user_id ],
] );

foreach( $comments as $comment ){
    // ...
}
```

Comment: is there a particular place where I should put this code? Thank you

Comment: If you don't understand where to put this code, I'm afraid I can't help you...